# Express Not Redirecting for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm using React and sending a req.params.id to my express backend through a GET request. If it's successful, it sends the JSON. If not, it should redirect to a certain URL. But it's not sending that redirect request to react? When I test it in Postman, it's working properly when I swap it out for a res.status(401).json({unauthorized: you don't have authorization to view this});

Any suggestions?

```
router.get('/score/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { 
    session: false
}), (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        user: req.user.id
    })
    .then(user => {
        Scores.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(score => {
                // Check for score owner to prevent anyone from accessing score
                if (score.user.toString() !== req.user.id && req.user.role !== 'admin') {

                    return res.redirect('/not-authorized');

                } else {
                    res.json(score);
                }


            })
            .catch(err => res.status(404).json({
                scorenotfound: 'Score not found'
            }));
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you trying redirect somewhere within your react app or to another website? Also, are you using react-router?

Comment: Trying to redirect to another route in my app, which is another page/component through React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect function redirects you to a new route inside your node js app. You should return to your react app a piece of information for example:

```
if (score.user.toString() !== req.user.id && req.user.role !== 'admin') {
        return res.status(403).send({ error: "not-authorized" });
} else {
        res.json(score);
}
```

then you can handle it in your react app and make the app redirect you to the right route.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there some form of tutorial I can use to learn how to do that? I've literally searched for 2 days and cannot find what I'm looking for. I'm really unfamiliar with handling things in react with state and stuff. (Even though I've watched tutorials it's still kinda confusing).

Comment: Personally I've used react router to handle the redirect https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow 

I'll be honest the new spread operator makes reading this really difficult. But, it's the best I'm aware of.

Comment: @Buckyx55 you can use the Redirect from react-router-dom.

take a look at this article <https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a>

probably you have a function to try to do the login, you just need to verify your response... if it has an error or something you use something like this.


if(response.data.error) {
  return <Redirect to='/target' />
}

it is just an example.